# How to place a Text on an animated Image

Tags: objective-c

How to place a text or label on a moving image. so that if the image is moved or animated the text should on the image should also move. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the label as a subview of the UIImageView?

```
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"]];
[imageV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 10)];
label.text = @"Test";

[imageV addSubview:label];
```

Just an example...

Comment: no i couldnt add the label inside the image view :-(